# Detecting Period Symbol as not Valid against Number Input Pattern Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input tag of type number with pattern validation attached to it that has at least taken care of eliminating the 'e' '+' '-' characters from being input. However the '.' symbol still gets through for some reason. Here are the relevant portions of code from my program:

```
<input type="number" id="job-priority" min="1" max="99" pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="1 (High) — 99 (Low)" style="width:186px; padding-left:14px; text-align:center;">

document.getElementById('job-priority').addEventListener('input', function () {
    // Check that characters typed into job priority field are valid.
    if (!document.getElementById('job-priority').validity.valid) {
        var value = document.getElementById('job-priority').value;
        value = value.slice(0,-1);
        document.getElementById('job-priority').value = value;
    }
});
document.getElementById('job-priority').addEventListener('change', function () {
    // Check that number entered into job priority stays within limits.
    var value = Number(document.getElementById('job-priority').value);
    var min = Number(document.getElementById('job-priority').min);
    var max = Number(document.getElementById('job-priority').max);
    if (value < min)
        document.getElementById('job-priority').value = min;
    else if (value > max)
        document.getElementById('job-priority').value = max;
});
```

From my own research on this up to this point, I have come across one previous question post on StackOverflow regarding input patterns with input type number. That post, in short, confirms that input patterns don't work for input type number. It proposes the solution to just use input type text instead with a pattern to allow only numbers through. However, I want to keep the input type to number because of the up/down arrows that increase/decrease the number in the input field. I would be willing to change the input type to text only if their is a way to keep the up/down arrows in question.

I also see that if I remove the pattern from the input tag, my event listener for 'input' still successfully takes care of not allowing the 'e' '+' '-' characters somehow. Of course, the '.' symbol is still being allowed when it shouldn't. So I guess at least I confirmed that the pattern wasn't actually doing anything from what I can tell.

More specifically, if the '.' is typed as the first character, the validation check successfully works and nothing appears in the input field which is the desired behavior. However, if the first character typed is a number and then second character typed in is the '.' symbol, then for some reason the '.' symbol appears when it should not have.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution to my problem.

```
document.getElementById('job-priority').addEventListener('input', function () {
    // Check that characters typed into job priority field are valid.
    document.getElementById('job-priority').type = 'text';
    if (!document.getElementById('job-priority').validity.valid) {
        var value = document.getElementById('job-priority').value;
        value = value.slice(0,-1);
        document.getElementById('job-priority').value = value;
    }
    document.getElementById('job-priority').type = 'number';
});
```

You'll see that what I did was change the input type to 'text' temporarily just for the input validation. Then, as soon as it's done, immediately change the input type back to 'number'.